# Date_field: how to set maximum date while using Bootstrap datepicker?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, datepicker

For a date variable I have the following code in different places of my app:

```
<%= f.date_field :date, required: true, 'data-provide': 'datepicker' %>
<%= f.text_field :date, required: true, 'data-provide': 'datepicker' %>
```

So on some occasions it uses a `date_field` while on other occasions a `text_field`. It uses Bootstrap datepicker.

I would like to add a maximum date that is allowed to be selected. `Date_field` offers the option `max` to set this. However, when I added this, I could still select any day in the future. So this didn't work and I thought it might be because of Bootstrap datepicker. So I also added the method that datepicker offers namely `endDate`.

I now have the code below, but I can still select any date in the future I want. Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

```
<% end_date = Time.zone.now + 100.days %>
<%= f.date_field :date, required: true, 'data-provide': 'datepicker', max: end_date, id: 'date' %>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#date').datepicker({
      endDate: end_date;
    });
  });
</script>

<%= f.text_field :date, required: true, 'data-provide': 'datepicker', id: 'date' %>
# Using the same JavaScript code
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way your code is written, you are putting the literal string "end_date" into your javascript. If you want this to be ruby, you would need to wrap it in `<%= %>` brackets. That being said, the syntax for the bootstrap datepicker is to use a number followed by 'd'. Try:

```
  $('#date').datepicker({
    endDate: "+100d";
  });
```

Comment: Thanks, I changed it to "100d" but this didn't seem to make a difference. I can still select any date in the future.

Comment: If I write it on one line something does happen: `$('#expiration_date').datepicker({endDate: "100d"});`. Now I can't select a date later than today (instead of 100 days into the future).

Comment: Found it: it needs to be "+100d". So the + was missing. Would you agree now that datepicker manages the max date, there's no use for keeping `max: end_date` in the `date_field` line?

Comment: Yes. That seems reasonable. Especially if it was not causing the behavior you expected it to.